# mouse click event with c# for kinect

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, kinect

i was wondering how could i emulate a mouse click with c# with kinect. I was trying to recognize a certain pattern with my hands in order to click the mouse, but i am not familiar with the mouse event. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was a bit confused by your question... Trying to call the mouse event, or recognize patterns with your hands?

For the first option, you can call an OnMouseClick event. You could probably call it for one object, but you would probably have to make it global (check out [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/dd375b80-775e-4c8b-ab25-2985f272ddec)). For the second, one way would be to use [AForge](http://aforgenet.com/) with your kinect (sorry if I use too much links but [this](http://www.conquex.com/microsoft-kinect-and-aforge-net/) is a good one). You could even just use AForge with a camera to detect mouse clicks. For instance (another link) [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/articles/hands_gesture_recognition/) is an example from one of the AForge developers.
Another way to do it would be to use [emgucv](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which I am not familiar with.

Anyways, good luck! +1 on your question (for what you are trying to do).